# AppsFlyer Deeplink not working in Swift iOS

Tags: appsflyer-ios-sdk

I am using an appsflyer deeplink to open the app but it is redirecting to the appstore instead of taking to the app which is already installed.

Any response will be appreciated.

The link is already generated and integrated in the xcode. every time i click on the link it takes to the appstore.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?